# How can I use the va_list correctly?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to have something like a cross platform `snprintf` function, so I'm trying to use this (perhaps there are other solutions, but I'm wondering exactly that):

```
void string_print(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
#ifdef _WIN32
    sprintf_s(str, size, format, args);
#else
    snprintf(str, size, format, args);
#endif
    va_end(args);
}
```

Example of usage:

```
// timeStepNumber == 1
char fileName[40];  
string_print(fileName, 40, "Flow%d.dat", timeStepNumber);
```

But in this case I have `fileName == "Flow-14843.dat"`, although `va_arg(args, int) == 1`. Can anybody explain, what maybe wrong in the `string_print` function?

Comment: I assume you have verified that 'timeStepNumber == 1' by displaying the value prior to calling 'string_print()' ?

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Yes - prior to calling ``string_print``, and also inside (before an actual calling ``snprintf``)

Comment: why have you elected to use 'snprintf()' instead of using 'int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap);' ?

Comment: because of "copy-paste" =) ``snprintf`` was used originally in code - looks like it's an error I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use vsnprintf/vsnprintf_s functions with vararg lists.

`vsnprintf(str, size, format, args);`

Answer (score 1):

[As indicated by imbtfab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578245/21926), use `vsnprintf()` in place of `snprintf()` and `_vsnprintf()` in place of `sprintf_s`.